# What class of functions swap inequalities when applied to both sides?

Tags: functions, inequality

I know that $x = y \implies f(x) = f(y)$, but for what $f$ does $x < y \implies f(x) > f(y)$?

As a child, I had to be taught that $$x < y \implies -x > -y$$
Today I realized that $$x < y \implies \frac1x > \frac1y$$
Thus, the set of functions that meet my criteria is a superset of $$\{f(x) = nx \mid n < 0\} \oplus \{f(x) = x^m \mid m < 0\}$$

Where I've used the exclusive or rather than union because if you swap the inequality twice, you have a net result of zero (like a double negative).

Are there any functions that I'm missing? Keep in mind it is not sufficient that there exist an $x, y$ pair such that $$x < y \wedge f(x) > f(y)$$ I require that $$x < y \implies f(x) > f(y)$$ be true for all $x, y$ where $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ (if you'd like to deal with complex numbers as well, be my guest. I simply restrict it to $\mathbb{R}$ as I have little experience with the complex plane.)

Comment: decreasing functions swap the inequality.

Comment: What you described is precisely the collection of (strictly) decreasing functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: This seems rather obvious in hindsight.